# How to store data in a dynamic 2D array, declared inside a struct which is also used by another struct in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct

I am trying to debug a code from someone else and I cannot read data from a file into a variable, declared in a header file. I'm attaching the snippet from the .C as well as .H files.

//main.C

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "test.H"
int main()
{
 Initialize();
 return(0);
}
```

//test.C.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "test.H"
#include "BB.H"
using namespace std;

#define file_to_be_read "file_to_be_read"

int NUM[10] = {3,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,3,4};

OBJECTS * OBJECTS::m_list[10];
void OBJECTS::createObjects()
{
 //cout << "Print somethin'" << endl;
 OBJECTS * objs = new OBJECTS(A_size, NUM[A]);
 m_list[A] = objs;
 objs = new OBJECTS(B_size, NUM[B]);
 m_list[B] = objs;
 objs = new OBJECTS(C_size, NUM[C]);
 m_list[C] = objs;     
 objs = new OBJECTS(D_size, NUM[D]);
 m_list[D] = objs;
 objs = new OBJECTS(E_size, NUM[E]);
 m_list[E] = objs;     
 objs = new OBJECTS(F_size, NUM[F]);
 m_list[F] = objs;
 objs = new OBJECTS(G_size, NUM[G]);
 m_list[G] = objs;     
 objs = new OBJECTS(H_size, NUM[H]);
 m_list[H] = objs;
 objs = new OBJECTS(I_size, NUM[I]);
 m_list[I] = objs;     
 objs = new OBJECTS(J_size, NUM[J]);
 m_list[J] = objs;

 char name[100];
 sprintf(name,file_to_be_read);
 ifstream fin(name);

 // Load the file.
 string buf;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
  objs = m_list[i];
  for (int j = 0; j < NUM[i]; j++)
  {
   fin >> buf; // read separator line.
   cout << buf << endl;
   for (int k = 0; k < objs->size_m; k++)
   {
    fin >> buf;
    cout << buf << endl;
    fin >> objs->sub_objs[j].coords[k][0];  // Segmentation error 
    fin >> objs->sub_objs[j].coords[k][1];
   }
  }
 }
}
void Initialize() 
{
 OBJECTS::createObjects();
}
```

test.H file

```
#ifndef _test_H
#define _test_H

#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

#define A 0
#define B 1
#define C 2
#define D 3 
#define E 4
#define F 5
#define G 6
#define H 7 
#define I 8 
#define J 9

extern int NUM[];


//////////////////////
struct SUBOBJECTS
{

 SUBOBJECTS(int size)
 {
  coords = new double[size][2];
 }

 double (*coords)[2];
};
//////////////////////
struct OBJECTS 
{
 OBJECTS(int size, int number) : 
 size_m(size), num_m(number)
 {
  std::vector<SUBOBJECTS> sub_objs(number,size);
 }

 static void createObjects();
 static OBJECTS * m_list[10];

 SUBOBJECTS * sub_objs;
 int size_m;
 int num_m;
};
void Initialize();

#endif
```

//BB.H

```
 const int A_size = 2;
 const int A_size = 2;
 const int B_size = 3;
 const int C_size = 3;
 const int D_size = 2;
 const int E_size = 2;
 const int F_size = 1;
 const int G_size = 1;
 const int H_size = 3;
 const int I_size = 3;
 const int J_size = 2;
```

file_to_be_read

```
#######################  
0.658 1.291  
1.891 1.753  
#----------------------  
2.570 2.955  
3.747 3.417  
#----------------------  
3.658 4.141  
5.096 2.800  
#######################  
5.293 1.842  
4.518 1.511  
6.215 1.450  
#----------------------  
6.113 3.239  
5.960 3.966  
7.033 2.842  
#######################  
0.658 1.291  
1.919 1.720  
2.404 2.998  
#----------------------  
3.674 3.536  
4.073 3.004  
4.379 4.781  
#----------------------  
3.915 5.534  
3.063 5.270  
4.417 6.366  
#######################  
5.500 5.125  
5.850 4.551  
#----------------------  
5.997 5.958  
0.658 1.291  
#----------------------  
1.899 1.698  
2.455 3.008  
#----------------------  
3.751 3.337  
4.562 3.037  
#######################  
3.962 4.032  
2.945 4.456  
#----------------------  
1.997 4.312  
3.125 4.921  
#----------------------  
5.212 4.220  
5.982 3.896  
#----------------------  
5.386 4.685  
0.658 1.291  
#----------------------  
1.873 1.711  
2.481 2.999  
#######################  
1.556 4.164  
#----------  
0.658 1.291  
#######################  
1.891 1.753  
#----------------------  
0.658 1.291  
#----------------------  
1.919 1.720  
#######################  
0.658 1.291  
1.841 1.793  
1.894 1.773  
#######################  
0.658 1.291  
1.894 1.773  
2.486 3.006  
#----------------------  
3.032 2.690  
3.045 1.710  
3.546 3.682  
#----------------------  
3.561 4.989  
3.219 5.337  
3.915 5.627  
#######################  
3.995 3.220  
3.982 2.227  
#---------------------  
4.348 3.863  
1.467 4.890  
#---------------------  
1.467 4.890  
2.201 4.539  
#---------------------  
2.842 3.762  
2.115 5.051
```

I understand there's something wrong with the `sub_objs` definition. But I can't figure out what. And I had to modify the variables and code slightly in order to post on a public forum. Please keep in mind any error pertaining to that and help!

Comment: Do you get build errors (you should!)? Then please include the complete output from the build, in full and unedited. Include it in the question body by editing your question. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, whenever you think you need a "dynamic array", your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Also, instead of a vector of arrays (or vector of vectors), have you though about better grouping the values in a *structure*, so you only have a vector (or array) of structures instead? That might help you fix some of your problems (and might even be more logical).

Comment: I have edited the code and now it compiles fine and reproduces the segmentation error at the mentioned line.

Comment: What do you expect this line does `std::vector<SUBOBJECTS> sub_objs(number,size);`?

Answer (score 1):

In the `OBJECTS` constructor you have the following line:

```
std::vector<SUBOBJECTS> sub_objs(number,size);
```

That declares a *local* variable with the name `sub_objs`. This variables goes out of scope once the destructor exits. It is also not related in any way with the `OBJECTS::sub_objs` *member* variable.

So you are never initializing the `OBJECTS::sub_objs` member variable anywhere, which means its value will be *indeterminate* and using it in any way will lead to *undefined behavior* and the crash you're seeing.

There are two solutions:

1. Since the *member* variable is a pointer you need to use `new[]` to allocate the memory for it.
2. Change the type of the member variable to a vector, and construct it in the `OBJECTS` constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

So what does this part do?

```
struct SUBOBJECTS
{
 SUBOBJECTS(int size)
 {
  coords = new double[size][2]; // [2]
 }
 double (*coords)[3]; // [3]
};
```

It declares an array of 3 doubles and then news an array of 2 doubles.
This might cause serious problems.

if `num` is size is 10 you allocate room for 20 doubles but declares it for 30 doubles.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I have edited the code and it now reproduces the error I want it to.